# Issue While Pushing New ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am using `ECSlidingViewController`.

What I want that if my app is first launch the I Want to show Terms and Conditions and when User Accepts it then I am changing `ViewController` to `ECSlidingViewController`

My Code is:

```
 - (IBAction)didTapAccept:(id)sender
 {
       ECSlidingViewController *nextScr = (ECSlidingViewController *) [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ECSlidingViewController"];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextScr animated:YES];
 }
```

**Problem:** The Problem is that When my app runs first time the app crashes without giving any log or warning, after i stop and run again it works fine.

My Storyboard Setup 
[image]

When I Debug i found that my app crashes in `ECSlidingViewController.m` file.
But it is a library file so haven't changed anything.

Code From `ECSlidingViewController.m`

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
if (!self.topViewController)
{
    [NSException raise:@"Missing topViewController"
                                         format:@"Set the topViewController before loading ECSlidingViewController"];
}
self.topViewController.view.frame = [self topViewCalculatedFrameForPosition:self.currentTopViewPosition]; //crashes
[self.view addSubview:self.topViewController.view];
[super viewDidLoad];

}
```

I have mentioned where the app crahses. But In second time run it works fine.
What's the issue with it.

Comment: Have you tried it on a physical device, or just the simulator?

Comment: I tried in Device also...in device also app crashes frst time and in second time it works fine @AdrianB

Comment: Can you try to put a seque between the I agree button and the slidingviewcontroller? That's my current setup and it works.